# Can't test timer in react using vitest (jest)

Tags: reactjs, testing, setinterval, react-testing-library, vitest

I have this simple component in react and I want to test it but I cannot find a way to mock the `setInterval` in order to trigger the timer.

The `count` value is `0` all the time but when I run the component it's working.

**UPDATE**: I've added [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-va2jnh?file=src/App.test.jsx) sample respository on stackblitz for running this test.

This is my test file:

```js
import {
  render,
  screen
} from "@testing-library/react";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { expect, test, vi } from "vitest";

function Timer() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    let timer = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(v => v + 1)
    }, 1000)
    return () => clearInterval(timer)
  }, [])
  return <div>{count}</div>
}
test("should render correctly", () => {
    vi.useFakeTimers();
    render(<Timer />);
    vi.advanceTimersByTime(2000);
    screen.debug();
    expect(screen.getByText("2")).toBeDefined();
});
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. Does it work if you call `setInterval()` outside of a component scope?

Comment: How do you mean? I was testing a component which uses `react-countdown-circle-timer` package but I found out I cannot trigger the timer in it so I tried to test a simple `setInterval`. @Halcyon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was with vitest not being able to notice the dom changes made during the test. The dom update code should be wrapped within an `act` method from `react-dom/test-utils`.

So `vi.advanceTimersByTime(2000);` must be in `act`.

```js
act(() => {
    vi.advanceTimersByTime(2000);
});
```

Theis is the [link](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/1983#issuecomment-1238794400) to the guthub issue I opened for this problem